# How to get detailed data from API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I have a task to do. I have to get data from Pokemon API, and show them on website.
I need to show name of Pokemon, his HP, attack, defense value and Pokemon in which it evolves. I have a problem with getting the last value.

My code right now:

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25/'

}).done(function (response) {

    $('h1').append(response.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + response.name.slice(1)); // name
    $('li').first().append(response.stats[5].base_stat); // hp
    $('li').eq(1).append(response.stats[4].base_stat); // attack
    $('li').last().append(response.stats[3].base_stat); // defense
    console.log(response.types[0].type.url); // i console log link from witch i want to get value of evolves Pokemon
    //$('.evolution-chain').append(); place for the correct code

}).fail(function (error) {

    console.log(`error ${error.status}`);

});
```

This is a link from which I am get the "Raichu" name. How i can do it?

```
pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/13/ // second object in Pokemon Array.
```

My ideas (but I'm not sure if it's a good thing):

- create an array of two links on top, and use the each loop on ajax.
- create another ajax, especially for the last value.

But I'm guessing that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can make an inner ajax request to get the Pokemon type name:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25/'
}).done(function (response) {
  $('h1').append(response.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + response.name.slice(1)); // name
  $('li').first().append(response.stats[5].base_stat);
  $('li').eq(1).append(response.stats[4].base_stat);
  $('li').last().append(response.stats[3].base_stat);

  var typeUrl = response.types[0].type.url;
  $.ajax({
    url: typeUrl
  }).done(function (response) {
    var name = response.name;
    console.log(name);
    $('.evolution-chain').append(name);
  });
}).fail(function (error) {
  console.log(`error ${error.status}`);
});
```

However, if you can use ES2017+ abilities and are looking for a more elegant solution, it's better to use async/await:

```
async function getData() {
  let typeUrl = '';
  try {
    const response = await $.ajax({
      url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25/'
    });

    $('h1').append(response.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + response.name.slice(1)); // name
    $('li').first().append(response.stats[5].base_stat); // hp
    $('li').eq(1).append(response.stats[4].base_stat); // attack
    $('li').last().append(response.stats[3].base_stat); // defense

    typeUrl = response.types[0].type.url;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(`error ${error}`);
  }

  try {
    const type = await $.ajax({
      url: typeUrl
    });

    const name = type.name;
    console.log(name);

    $('.evolution-chain').append(name);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(`error ${error}`); 
  }
}

getData();
```